# Python - Getting HttpSession java attributes?

Tags: java, python, session, servlets, client-server

I'm developing a client/server application using:

- `Java` `HttpServlet` (Server side)
- `Python` application (Client side) using `Session` class to making requests to the Server

It is possible for a `Python`'s `Session` object to get `HttpSession` attributes' of Java Servlet?
I tried to use `.__getattribute__` method of Session but apparently, it doesn't find the corrispondent attribute.

Comment: What is your Python's `Session` class?

Comment: I found `Session` class from `requests` library. But after many tries I realized that a Python `Session` object is not the same of a Java `HttpSession` object, so I think that a way to transfer `HttpSession`'s attributes to a Python client could be sending them through `serialization`.

Comment: Why not pass the attributes just by the http body?

Comment: Yes,at the end I tried this solution. I passed attributes stored in HettpSession(Java objects)  in http response (serializing them with Gson)  so that I got them in the Python client and deserialized in Python objects, although I'm not sure if this is a good/efficient solution.